# How to display or download the contains of a pdf file using webservice?

Tags: javascript, web-services, pdf

first of all i am quite knew at webservices and javascript.

I am trying to call a web service that returns a pdf file in this format :

[image]

In order to call the pdf i am using res.body just like the code below :

```
    var url="https://........../......./..../..";
    var options = {
  "rejectUnauthorized": false,
  "method": "GET",
  "url": url,
 "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Basic EJFHUygdiAISDGIF",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
 
};



request(options, (err, res) => {

  if (res.statusCode == 200 )  {
   
    conversation.logger().info("pdf:" + res.body); // in order to check the content of the pdf in the platform i use
  }
});
```

My problem here is that i dont know how to download or display the pdf content .

Any help would be valuable.

Comment: You have downloaded it. Do you mean "Save it to a file"? That depends on how you are running your JS. The answer will be different in Node.js, browsers, WSH, etc.

Comment: If `request` is [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request): Stop using it. It's deprecated.

Comment: Hello again , first of all i am using Node.js . Basically I have the pdf in the format shown above . My question really is how can i desplay it in the normal pdf form , in order to read it and see what is inside . Again i am very new and unexperienced ,so , every comment and observation would be trully valuable for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change content type to pdf

```
"headers": {
    "Authorization": "Basic EJFHUygdiAISDGIF",
    "Content-Type": "application/pdf"
  }
```

Comment: Why? They aren't POSTing a PDF to the API (they shouldn't have a Content-Type there are all since they aren't POSTing JSON either).

Comment: Because it's requesting get, not post :)

Comment: As I said, that's a reason to remove the `Content-Type` header, not one to change it to a different lie.

Comment: The requestor needs to respect what the server declares it's sending in the response.